# Laravel 5.4 composer update error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to update composer but getting errors

here is the link for error log: https://pastebin.com/JNT7Wi15

> Laravel Version: 5.4 Php version: PHP
>   7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 08:53:57) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Here is my `composer.json` file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "0.8.1",
    "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "2.*",
    "intervention/image": "~2.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade the composer command itself, or upgrade the dependencies of the current project?

Comment: try to remove the vendor folder then do composer update

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz still same error

Comment: @Quezler im trying to follow this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314189/laravel-5-intervention-image-upload-multiple-size?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa in order to create different sizes of image

Comment: Seems like one of the packages required laravel 5.2 i guess but your installation used 5.4.*. To be exact this package "barryvdh/laravel-cors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "0.8.1",
    "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "2.*",
    "intervention/image": "~2.1"
},
```

I found a solution for this issue. I just removed `"barryvdh/laravel-cors":"0.8.0"` from `composer.json`, because Laravel 5.4 doesn't support `barryvdh/laravel-cors`. So after removing that line I run `composer update` and it works.